# vivado: unused sequential element was removed

Tags: fpga, vivado

Let's suppose I have the following VHDL code that i'm synthesizing with Vivado:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity example1 is
    port (
        aclk     :in  std_logic; 
        aresetn  :in  std_logic; 

        ren      :in  std_logic; 
        wen      :in  std_logic;         
        count    :out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of example1 is
   signal reg_count :unsigned(7 downto 0);
   signal sel       :std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

begin

count <= std_logic_vector(reg_count);
sel   <= ren & wen;

process(aclk, aresetn)
begin
    if (aresetn = '0') then
        reg_count     <= (others => '0');

    elsif (rising_edge(aclk)) then

        case sel is        
        when "00"   => reg_count <= reg_count;            
        when "01"   => reg_count <= (reg_count + 1);            
        when "10"   => reg_count <= (reg_count - 1);
        when "11"   => reg_count <= reg_count;            
        when others => null;        
        end case;
    end if;
end process;

end architecture;
```

How can I modify the above code to prevent the following  synthesis warning messages:

```
[Synth 8-6014] Unused sequential element reg_count_reg was removed.
```

Should I take this warning message seriously?  I looks like its valid code sythesizable VHDL code to me.

Comment: Could it be that 'count' is not used and therefore the tool optimizes back to the source? Or 'ren' & 'wen' are always zero?

Comment: You are looking at the top level file... I made this file as an fpga top level without any other file.

Comment: Therefore it’s completely impossible that it’s not used.

Comment: I got the same message but on schematic there are some FDCE named reg_count_reg. So I don"t know why Vivado tell that but the schematic looks correct. I think you can ignore this warning.

Comment: I noticed that vivado tends to flag conversions from unsigned to std_logic_vector as "unused and removed" for some reason, even when this isn't true.  maybe the compiler is just getting confused about have two copies of the same signal around and wrongly reports removing one of them as removed when they are really the same signal with different representations (unsigned vs. std_logic_vector)

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with vivado 2017.1.

the xilinx forum talked about it: https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Many-spurious-quot-Synth-8-6014-Unused-sequential-element-was/td-p/769636

You can safely ignore this warning as it doesn't affect you synthesis result.